# Jquery-ui draggable scroll vertical only

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

So I have a fixed droppable div in the bottom right of my screen. I have a list of draggables that can be dragged into the trash (the fixed droppable) but I don't want the horizontal scrollbar to appear when dragging them near the trash. I don't want the draggables to be able to scroll horizontally. There are other droppables further down on the page that they can be dropped into so they must scroll vertically to get to them.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mZFEk/3/) of the the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `containment` option ([doc](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment)) on the draggable elements. This way you can constrain their movement into the BODY element:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    ...
    containment: 'body',
    ...
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/2cYTt/)**

Comment: But I can't drag it down to the droppables.

Comment: Sure you can (or I don't get exactly the problem). The body will still scroll its viewport but will no extend if the cursor goes too far bottom or right.

Comment: The problem now is that the body doesn't go all the way to the bottom.

Comment: It looks like @Didier Ghys solution works fine, just tested it in your fiddle.

Comment: @xCRKx TyPHooN I did test it and it blocks me from pulling the draggables down to the droppables.

Comment: You are using IE ? It is also not working in IE for me. Probably you should give the body an height of 99/100% (jsfiddle refuses to work right now so I can't test)

Comment: @Didier Ghys I figured it out... The reason it is being blocked is because those elements at the bottom are either fixed or absolute position not causing the body to expand it's height. This was not a problem in my live version but I had a div with a set height which grew bigger than that height so I removed the height and it now workds. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 31):

In order to only allow vertical dragging, you must set the "axis" property of the draggable this way:

```
$( "selector" ).draggable({ 
    axis: "y"
});
```

And if you already have an initialized draggable object, you must set it this way:

```
$( "selector" ).draggable( "option", "axis", "y" );
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I only wanted it to "scroll" vertically and it can move horizontally. The question has already been answered but Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: this was just the thing I was looking for

Comment: I have been looking for this too. Thanks